# Azure: How to connect one cloud service with other in one virtual network

Tags: asp.net, wcf, azure, cloud

I want deploy  backend WCF service in WebRole in Cloud Service 1 only with Internal Endpoint.
And deploy ASP.NET MVC frontend in WebRole in Cloud Service 2.

Is it possible to use Azure Virtual Netowork to call backend from frontend by Internal Endpoint ?

**UPDATED:** I am just trying build simple SOA architect like this:

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by putting them in separate cloud services? Is this primarily for deployment reasons?

Comment: I want deploy both application separately

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No.

An internal endpoint essentially means that the role instance has been configured to accept traffic on a given port, but that port can NOT receive traffic from outside of the cloud service (hence it being "internal" to the cloud service). Internal endpoints are also not load balanced so you're going to need to "juggle" traffic management from the callers yourself.

Now here is where the issues arise, a virtual network allows you to securely traverse cloud service boundaries, letting a role instance in cloud service 1 call a role instance in cloud service 2. However, to do this, the calling role instance needs to know how to address the receiving instance. If they were in the same cloud service, they you can crawl the cloud service topology via the RoleEnvironment class. But this class only works for the cloud service its exists in, its not aware of a virtual network.

Now you could have the receiving role instance publish its FQDN to a shared area (say Azure table storage). However, a cloud service will only use its own internal DNS resolution (which only allows you to resolve short names in the same cloud service) unless you have configured the virtual network with a self-hosted DNS server.

So yes, you can do what you're trying to accomplish, but it does present some challenges. Given this, I'd have to argue if the convenience of separating for deployment enough to justify the additional complexity of the solution? If so, then I'd also look and see if perhaps there's a better way to interconnect the two services rather then direct calls (like a queue based pattern).

Comment: Am i correct if say that main purpose of Azure Virtual Network is to connect many Virtual Machines, not cloud services? I just trying to build simple SOA architecture like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/C5Xan.png

Comment: A virtual network is a way to span cloud services resources (both PaaS and IaaS) as well as create hybrid solutions by making those cloud compute instances visible to on-premises networks. Keep in mind that a "cloud service" is just a virtual network container into which you place VMs (this includes PaaS role instances which are simply managed VMs).

Answer (score 1):

@BrentDaCodeMonkey makes some very valid points in his answer, so read that first.

I, personally, would not want to give up automatic discovery and scale via load balancing. My suggestion would be that you expose the WCF endpoint via an Azure Service Bus Relay endpoint. This will give you a "fixed" endpoint with which to communicate (solving the discovery issue) and infinite scalability because multiple servers can register and listen on the same Service Bus relay address. Additionally it introduces some basic security into the mix via shared key authentication when your web application(s) connect to your WCF services.

If you co-locate the Service Bus instance with your Cloud Services the overhead of the relay in the middle is totally negligible and, IMHO, worth it for the benefits explained above.